# Getting "Unexpected end of JSON input" error when making a fetch request in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

I am working on a simple project but keep running into the aforementioned error.
Additional Information:

The server is built using Node.js and Express.
The server code for the /api route is included in the question.
I'm also seeing a "405 Method Not Allowed" error.
Here's the client-side script:

```
checkButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const text = textArea.value;

  fetch("/api", {
    body: JSON.stringify({text}),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    method: "POST",
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      similarityPercentageSpan.textContent = `${data.similarity}%`;
      const processedText = data.processedText;
      // Do something with the processed text.
      console.log(processedText);
      const similarPartsList = document.getElementById("similarPartsList");
      similarPartsList.innerHTML = "";

      if (data.similarParts) {
        data.similarParts.forEach((part) => {
          const li = document.createElement("li");
          const link = document.createElement("a");
          link.href = part.url;
          link.textContent = part.text;
          li.appendChild(link);
          similarPartsList.appendChild(li);
        });
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    });
});
```

I have tried solutions from different blogs and even some posted here to no avail.
Server-side code:

```
    app.post("/api", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userText = req.body.text;
    const numberOfPhrases = 5;
    const phraseLength = 100;
    const extractedPhrases = getRandomPhrases(
      userText,
      numberOfPhrases,
      phraseLength
    );
    const scrapedAndProcesseContent = [];
    const similarityScore = calculateTextSimilarity(userText, cleanedContent);
    for (const phrase of extractedPhrases) {
      const searchResults = await fetchGoogleSearchResults(phrase);
      const cleanedContent = cleanScrapedContent(searchResults);
      const similarParts = [];
      for (const result of searchResults) {
        similarParts.push({
          text: result.text,
          url: result.url,
        });
      }

      scrapedAndProcesseContent.push({
        phrase,
        similarityScore,
        cleanedContent,
        similarParts: [],
      });
    }
    res.json({
      similarity: similarityScore,
      processedText: scrapedAndProcesseContent,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    res.status(500).json({error: "An error occurred"});
  }
});
```

Comment: `The server code for the /api route is included in the question.`  Did you forget to include, as I can only see client code ATM.

Comment: Had issues with word limits

Comment: Shouldn't `similarParts: []` be just `similarParts`?

Comment: `const similarityScore = calculateTextSimilarity(userText, cleanedContent);` you're using `cleanedContent` before you defined it in the `for` loop.

Comment: Maybe the response isn't a valid JSON string. Instead of `res.json()`, do `res.text()` and check the output to see if it's a valid JSON string or not.

Comment: Still the same after trying all suggested solutions here...